# Switching to a VPS

Tags: web-hosting, vps

Well, I know absolutely nothing about the subject, so I really need help.

I currently have a website running on google app-engine (Java) and I can't get it to what I want because of app engine's limitations (no full text search mainly). The traffic is low, never reached 15% of the free quota (around 1500 daily pageviews).

I also have 3 sites in drupal hosted in a shared hosting service, and this is giving me problems, because the server speed is awful. The sites are **VERY** low trafic, but load times are bad, and I might need to add more sites for some clients, so this will only get worse.

So, i'm planning to move all that to VPS. The question is, can I have 2 http servers running in the same VPS? because I will need Apache-php-drupal server and a java server (tomcat?).

I have really no idea on this, so any tip will be very helpful to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be migrated to ServerFault.com

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=6f680d1e7f05), they're really cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Your httpd and tomcat will be running on different ports on the same server

Some of the choices you have are

1. Forward a virtual directory of your httpd to the tomcat server (if you use one domain name)
2. Use URL based rules to forward the requests from the java app domain to the tomcat server

Comment: Ok, I thought that web servers should run always on port 80. 
And can I have several domains on my apache server and several domains on my tomcat server? Another question, for the sites I explaines in my question, do you think this will work fine on a linode 360 (linode.com)? Thanks!

Comment: VPS performance varies but for 1500 pageviews anything will do. But if you plan to host many web apps, do some benchmarking. request a trail with your prospective hosting providerand try to stress your server to see how it comes out